# ASP.Net Core app 502.3 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I have an ASP.Net core site which I am trying to host on Windows Server 2012/IIS8.0. I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) to deploy the site. When I try to browse the site I am getting:

HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

I have installed IHttpPlatformHandler 1.2

[image: HttpPlatformHandler 1.2 installed]

In the event viewer I am getting a useless error unless I am missing something here:

[image]

When I go manually in the wwwroot folder and run ../approot/web.cmd, the app starts in fact I can browse it by visiting localhost:5000 from the browser.

[image]

For me the problem seems to be that when the request is sent to IIS, the HttpPlatformHandler cannot start the app for some reason.

Comment: have you gone through jijiechen's steps in this link: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/466

Comment: if the app runs local but will not from off the server, have you checked your bindings?

Comment: I followed the steps of jijiechen's but to no avail. Regarding the bindings, I am pretty sure they are fine because otherwise I would not have 502.3 error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer is too late.  But what I did was essentially remove the codes from the offending View, and put them one at a time to isolate the error.

The culprit for me was a bad property set code (not supposed to be there, but added just for testing), and when I removed it, the error was gone!

Not yet sure why it triggered the 502.3 Gateway error instead of another more related error (if anybody can explain, that will be great!).  But thought I'd share this in case it helps somebody else with similar error.

**IN VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Same as above</label>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="IsSamePhone" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**IN MODEL**

```
public bool IsSamePhone
{
    get
    {
        return IsSamePhoneNumbers(); 
    }
    // This bad set code was the cause of the 502.3 Gateway Error.  
    // The error disappeared once this was commented out.
    //set
    //{
    //  IsSamePhone = value;
    //}
}
```